# Character encoding issue when importing CSV from Excel?

Tags: php, excel, csv, character-encoding

I have a PHP script which exports a CSV file.  My users then edit the file in Excel, save it, and re-upload it.

If they type a euro symbol into a field, when the file is uploaded, the euro symbol, and everything afterwards is missing. I'm using the **str_getcsv** function.

If I try to convert the encoding (say to UTF-8), the euro symbol disappears, and I get a missing character marker (usually represented by a blank square or a question mark in a diamond).

How to I convert the encoding to UTF-8, but also keep the euro symbol (and other non-standard characters)?

**Edit:**

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Decodes html entity encoded characters back to their original
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param String The element of the array to process
 * @param Mixed The key of the current element of the array
 * @return void
 */
public function decodeArray(&$indexValue, $key)
{
    $indexValue = html_entity_decode($indexValue, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'Windows-1252');
}

/**
 * Parses the contents of a CSV file into a two dimensional array
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param String The contents of the uploaded CSV file
 * @return Array Two dimensional-array.
 */
public function parseCsv($contents)
{
    $changes = array();
    $lines = split("[\n|\r]", $contents);

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = utf8_encode($line);
        $line = htmlentities($line, ENT_NOQUOTES);
        $lineValues = str_getcsv($line);
        array_walk($lineValues, 'decodeArray');
        $changes[] = $lineValues;
    }

    return $changes;
```

I have also tried the following instead of the utf8_encode function:

```
    iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $line);
```

And also just:

```
    $line = htmlentities($line, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'Windows-1252');
```

With the utf8_encode function, the offending character is removed from the string.  With any other method, the character and everything after the character is missing.

**Example:**

The field value : "Promo € Mobile"

is interpreted as : "Promo  Mobile"

Comment: What have you used so far? try to post some of the enconding code in order to help you.

Comment: what character for the euro symbol is being put into the exported CSV? hint: open the csv in notepad and see what it shows. its probably something thats breaking the encapsulation of the variables in the csv or perhaps the csv needs encapsulation adding to its save options.

Comment: works for me: http://3v4l.org/9b3s3.
consider the input CSV as invalid. could you upload the csv as binary somewhere?

Comment: Well, what encoding is the CSV in exactly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the encoding is "Windows-1252"

Answer (score 0):

Add these to the beginning of your CSV file

```
chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191)
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The field value : "Promo € Mobile" is now interpreted as : "Promo "